# Is rearranging words of text possible with RegEx?

Tags: regex, groovy, filemaker

I've got a list of devices in a database, such as `Model X123 ABC`. Another portion of the system accepts user input and needs to, as well as possible, match their entries to the existing devices. But the users have the ability to enter anything they want. They might enter the above model as `Model 100 ABC X123` or `Model X123`.

Understand, this is a general example, and the permutations of available models and matching user entries is enormous, and I'm just trying to match as many as possible so that the manual corrections can be kept to a minimum.

The system is built in FileMaker, but has access to pretty much any plugin I wish, which means I have access to Groovy, PHP, JavaScript, etc. I'm currently working with Groovy using the ScriptMaster plugin for other simple regex pattern matching elsewhere, and I'm wondering if the most straightforward way to do this is to use regex.

My thinking with regex is that I'm looking for patterns, but I'm unsure if I can say, "Assign this grouping to this pattern regardless of where it is in the order of pattern groups." Above, I want to find if the string contains three patterns: `(?i)\bmodel\b`, `(?i)\b[a-z]\d{3}\b`, and `(?i)\b[a-z]{3}\b`, but I don't care about what order they come in. If all three are found, I want to place them in that specific order: first the word "model", capitalized, then the all-caps alphanumeric code and finally the pure alphabetical code in all-caps.

Can (should?) regex handle this?

Comment: I believe this - reordering words according to their character composition - is something you could accomplish within Filemaker itself, using either a recursive custom function or a looping script. Not sure how useful this would be though, since the 4 words `Model 100 ABC X123` will never match the 3 words `Model X123 ABC`, no matter how you rearrange them.

Comment: In answer to the question title: possible yes, advisable no

Comment: In FileMaker alone you could compare two calculation fields as a multikey to get all records that match at least one word. And then use an unstored calculation to sort them by the number of matching words. In your example, you'd want to remove the word 'Model' from the multikey if it's in every product.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, @pft221, a direction I hadn't thought of. Perhaps I'll experiment with it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest tokenizing the input into words, matching each of them against the supported tokens, and assembling them into canonical categorized slots.

Even better would be to offer search suggestions when the user enters the information, and require the user to pick a suggestion.

But you *could* do it by (programmatically) constructing a monster regex pattern with all the premutations:

```
\b(?:(model)\s+([a-z]\d{3})\s+([a-z]{3})
    |(model)\s+([a-z]{3})\s+([a-z]\d{3})
    |([a-z]\d{3})\s+(model)\s+([a-z]{3})
    |([a-z]\d{3})\s+([a-z]{3})(model)
    |([a-z]{3})(model)\s+([a-z]\d{3})
    |([a-z]{3})\s+([a-z]\d{3})\s+(model)
)\b
```

It'd have to use named capturing groups but I left that out in the hopes that the above might be close to readable.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines after my original post, as the number of permutations is simply too many to write something like you show. Controlling user input isn't an option, unfortunately. This is data imported from a spreadsheet that we don't control. Regex just won't be the right tool for this job, unfortunately.

Comment: After tokenizing, a recursive decent parser could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your underlying objective -- is this to be able to match up like products (e.g., products with the same model number)? If so, a word permutations function like this one could be used in a calculated field to create a multikey: http://www.briandunning.com/cf/1535

If you need partial matching in FileMaker, you could also use a redux search function like this one: http://www.fmfunctions.com/fid/380

Feel free to PM me if you have questions that aren't a good format to post here.

Comment: Your second link seems to be no more available. Is there a new one for the same possible solution ?